# Angular Directives com métodos construtores de objetos

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou tentando criar uma diretiva que seja um input que disponibilize um objeto no $scope somente se ele for criado com sucesso pelo seu método construtor.

Quero que o valor somente seja atribuído à variável no escopo, se for resultado de um construtor de um objeto, que encapsula as regras de criação/validação no seu construtor.

Ao lado do input, a diretiva deve ter um span, onde exibirá erro de validação. Se o construtor não validar o valor, uma exception deve ser gerada e exibida em um campo ao lado, como validação.

Aqui, criei um objeto Cpf, que encapsula suas regras. A diretiva do angular fornece um input que gera o objeto no $scope somente se ele for criado com sucesso.

Criei essa Direcive e funciona. Porém, o tipo restrict: Element não permite reutilizar bem como um componente. Não posso declarar um placeholder no meu elemento personalizado, ou outras coisas que poderia aplicar diretamente no input.

Gostaria de saber como torná-lo em uma diretiva mais modular.

Talvez do tipo Attribute, para que eu possa decorar o input com outros atributos, como placeholder, ou uma máscara. Ou também, que use o ngModel para saber em qual variável colocar o objeto instanciado.

```js
//-------------Angular---------------------->

        var app = angular.module('teste', []);
        
//Diretiva:

        app.directive('sgInputModel', function(){
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    set : '&onSet'
                },
                template: '<input ng-model="modelo" ><span ng-bind="modeloErro"></span>',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                    scope.$watch('modelo', setModelo);
                    function setModelo(){
                        console.log(scope.modelo)
                        scope.modeloErro = '';
                        if(!scope.modelo)
                            return;
                        try{
                            scope.set({value:scope.modelo});
                        }catch(e){
                            scope.modeloErro = e.message;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

//Controller:

        app.controller('pedidoCtl', [
            '$scope',
            '$http',
            '$log',
            function ($scope, $http, $log, URL_SELECT) {
              
              $scope.sgSetCpf = function (value){
                    $scope.cpf = null;
                    if(value.length == 11)
                        $scope.cpf = new Cpf(value);
                };
              
              }]);



//-------------Objeto CPF---------------------->

    Cpf = function (cpf) {
        cpf = retirarCaracteres(cpf);
        if (!this.validar(cpf))
            throw new CpfException('Cpf inválido');
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'cpf', {
            value: cpf
        });
        
        if(!Cpf.instances[this.formatado]){
            Cpf.instances[this.formatado] = this;
        }
        else
            return Cpf.instances[this.formatado];
    };
    
    Cpf.instances = [];

    Object.defineProperties(Cpf.prototype, {
        formatado: {
            get: function(){
                return this.cpf.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})$/,"$1.$2.$3-$4");
            }
        },
        validar: {
            value: function(cpf){
                cpf = String(cpf);
                var numeros, digitos, soma, i, resultado, digitos_iguais;
                digitos_iguais = 1;
                if (cpf.length < 11)
                    return false;
                for (i = 0; i < cpf.length - 1; i++)
                    if (cpf.charAt(i) != cpf.charAt(i + 1))
                    {
                        digitos_iguais = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                if (!digitos_iguais)
                {
                    numeros = cpf.substring(0, 9);
                    digitos = cpf.substring(9);
                    soma = 0;
                    for (i = 10; i > 1; i--)
                        soma += numeros.charAt(10 - i) * i;
                    resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
                    if (resultado != digitos.charAt(0))
                        return false;
                    numeros = cpf.substring(0, 10);
                    soma = 0;
                    for (i = 11; i > 1; i--)
                        soma += numeros.charAt(11 - i) * i;
                    resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
                    if (resultado != digitos.charAt(1))
                        return false;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });

    Cpf.prototype.toString = function () {
        return this.formatado;
    };
    
    Cpf.prototype.valueOf = function(){
        return Number(this.ano + this.mes);
    };
    
    
    function CpfException(message) {
      this.name = 'CpfException';
      this.message= message;
    }
    CpfException.prototype = new Error();
    CpfException.prototype.constructor = CpfException;

    function retirarCaracteres(string){
      return String(string).replace(/\D/g, '');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="teste" ng-controller="pedidoCtl">
  
        Cpf:
        <sg-input-model 
            on-set="sgSetCpf(value)"
        ></sg-input-model>
        {{cpf.formatado}}
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia colocar mais varíaveis no scope e estar passando para elas o placeholder, por exemplo.

Você teria que modificar, também, o teu template para que aceite esse placeholder.

Você poderia colocar por exemplo todos os atributos de um input no scope e passar eles pelo scope.

Comment: Eu faria o mesmo, receberia as variáveis em atributos do elemento e atribuiria ao acope da diretiva